# Sharing resource files between Visual Studio and Intellij

Tags: cordova, intellij-idea

For my existing webpage (written in ASP.NET) I want to build an PhoneGap app with Intellij. For the sake of convenience I want to share some of my existing JavaScript / css files and images between the 2 projects. What I am missing is such a 'add file as link' functionality like in Visual Studio (or even in Eclipse).

I read something about Intellij artifacts but on the first view it doesn't look like what I need and second I am not able to edit this project then in Eclipse, Netbeans, ...

I know I could move the files to the app project and link them in the ASP.NET project but actually I want to keep my webpage project complete. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Open Module settings, select a module, click on "Add Content Root" and select the folder which contains files which you want to use. Then "Mark" the folder or it's subfolders as Resource.